# Why is brûler used differently in the question below?

Tags: grammaire

Why is the use of *brûler* in these two sentences different?

- *Ils se sont **brûlés** en faisant le barbecue*
- *Ils se sont **brûlé** les mains*

Comment: See point 2. in the other answer.